# How to rewrite the url in tornado

Tags: nginx, tornado

I'm learning tornado and nginx these days,and I'm confused about the url rewrite.

for example:if I wanna make url like this

**www.abc.com/username/projectname** ( which username and projectname are depend on the user )

I got two solution,first one is use Regular Expressions like

**(r'/(w+)/(w+)', IndexHandler)**

and trying to get **username** and **projectname** from the url and do some search in database

second solution is use nginx rewrite like this

**www.abc.com/username/projectname => abc.domian.com/?us=username&pj=projectname**

which solution is correct? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. In this case, personally, I would use the first form so the Tornado server can work whether nginx is present or not (more convenient for development and testing), but there are times when it is simpler to do rewrites at the nginx level.

Comment: Thanks Ben,so I can juse  use   get_argument  to get the parameter from user's input url  then do the search in database?

Comment: You can use get_argument() in the second form (with `?us=`). In the first form, values extracted from the path are passed in as arguments to your handler's get() method instead.

Comment: Would you mind give me an example? I used **get(self, input): self.write(input)** and wanna get "username/projectname" but failed.   It's work without "/" in it.Or maybe I should use something like self.request.uri?

Comment: If there are two sets of parentheses in your route, there will be two arguments in the get method: get(self, user, project)